# productsController is not initiated when i do hot restart , but when i do hot reload it works , flutter Getx

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-hotreload

I am working on a ecommerce-app , I'm using `Getx` for the state managment, I'm a newbie with `Getx` a little help would be appreciated.

I am using `firebase auth`, so when the app is navigated from the `login screen` everything is fine i.e `products are shown`,
But when when the user are `kept logged in`, `products are not shown` until **hard reloaded**,

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) {
    Get.put(ProductsController());
  });

  runApp(MyApp());
}


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: routes,
      home: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return HomeScreen();
              }
            }
            return const LoginScreen();
          }),
    );
```

**controllers.dart**

```
ProductsController productsController = ProductsController.instance;
```

**home.dart**

```
    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Popular Products"),
                PopularProducts(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
        );
  }
```

**Popular Products**

**These products are shown only after hot reload, it is not shown initially, this is something to do with `productController`**

```
class PopularProducts extends StatelessWidget {
  const PopularProducts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children:
                    productsController.products.map((ProductModel product) {
                  print("These are the products" + product.toString());
                  return ProductCard(product: product);
                }).toList()),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

The images are :
When hot restart:

[image]

When hot reload:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LMech replied
Obx() was missing!!

Now the code is

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Obx(                         --> Add this line
          () => Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children:
                      productsController.products.map((ProductModel product) {
                    print("These are the products" + product.toString());
                    return ProductCard(product: product);
                  }).toList()),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, my app wasn't loading the data fast enough and the widgets was already rendered, so i made a function to load the data and inside the build i used Obx() widget and called the function, but remember to but the function called with condition of the variable is empty